# Api error code 100

Tags: facebook, api

I get this error on my blog page now.
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/error/api?code=100&message=Param+show_faces+must+be+a+boolean&hash=AQCNFmFNw0GU83AX
I have no idea how to fix it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that this is about the Like Button/Like Box? You should specify this in your question!

If so, then you need to add the `show_faces` parameter/attribute as described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/#settings

Example:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```